# Excel Dependent Drop Down with Dupes in Column A

Tags: microsoft-excel

Trying to create a dependent Dropdown for column B based off of information in column A. Colum A has 30,00+ rows of data and some have the same value. However, if I create a reference column to =SORT(UNIQUE(A:A)) so that I only have one instance of repeated values in column A to choose from in my drop down list, how can I get the conditional drop down to look at column "A" and then return only the value in column B that correlates to the value in column "A" even if it is a duplicate. So in some instances I would only have one option to choose from since Column A has a unique value, but when the value is not unique, how can I have it return >1 value from column B to choose from in my dependent drop down. And I am looking at 30,000+ records. Creating the CONCAT route is not an option.

Comment: Use the `FILTER` function, and if it's something else, show what you want it to look like.

Comment: Can you add a mockup of what you have and what you want the result to look like? It would help us understand the ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the screenshot below, the unique list of categories for the dropdown Data Validation is generated with the formula

```
=UNIQUE(tblData[Category])
```

Note that there are several different subcategory values for the category "one" and value "one-1" appears twice.

The list with unique values for the subcategories as a dependent of the selected Category is created with the formula

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(tblData[subcategory],tblData[Category]=G2))
```

In words: filter the subcategories to the rows where the category equals the value selected in the dropdown, but return only unique values.

[image]

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.